# Reading configuration file and giving option to other class library which is having dependency on it

Tags: c#-4.0

There is a DLL which can expose different collection to different clients (Clients are DLLs who are going to use this DLL)based on its type. These collection will be made at run time by reading a configuration. Example: Collection of Fruit Type 1 : ["ORANGE" ,"MANGO" ] to one client Collection of Fruit Type 2 : ["JACK FRUIT" ,"MANGO" ] to other client.

Thanks,
Anil

Comment: What is your question here? And what effort did you put in this problem?

Comment: @dds Thanks for the interest in this query.

There is a DLL which can expose different collection to different clients (Clients are DLLs who are going to use this DLL)based on its type.

These collection will be made at run time by reading a configuration.

Example:

Collection of Fruit Type 1 : ["ORANGE" ,"MANGO" ] to one client

Collection of Fruit Type 2 : ["JACK FRUIT" ,"MANGO" ] to other client

Comment: Please edit your question and add this info there.

Comment: @dds I have modified the query.Please have a look.